# Oracle, 2 installations on one computer, TNSListener

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, tns

I have 2 versions of Oracle Database in one pc:

- 1st is oracle 11g in folder c:/xe...
- 2nd is oracle 12c in folder c:/app...

What is the problem - there's something wrong with environment in windows, because when I set ORACLE_BASE & ORACLE_HOME to `C:/xe`, listener from 12c doesn't work (not loadable error). Same scenario in other way - when BASE & HOME is set to `c:/app` - listener from `c:/xe` shows same error. On 11g there is database which I need the most so question - is there any possibility to make this database visible to oracle 12c? Or someone knows how to eliminate this loadable error?

Comment: Do you particularly want to run separate listeners? I'd just run the latest (12c) listener and have the 11g DB register its service against that - which it would do by default if that is on 1521, or you can specify the address/port with [the `LOCAL_LISTENER` initialisation setting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams120.htm#REFRN10082).

Comment: I want to by database worked. I could worked on 12c if my database from 11g would be seen.